# How to get away from the unfairness of being banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I heard people often said that there are no stupid questions; but Stack Overflow bans people from asking stupid questions.

I have noticed that some people ask questions that do not follow the FAQ for asking questions on this site, but; however, due to their reputation, they are considered talented and their questions are not banned or at least not immediately.

Unfortunately it seems if the same question is asked by a guy with low reputation (e.g. me), then some people that try to get the points will ban the question right away.

I have asked only 2 questions with my other accounts, and I got a ban from asking questions on this site. So why bother to create this kind of site if you are looking to ban people from asking questions?

Sorry I am being impolite, but I am totally mad.

Comment: Two commas and three periods....wow. If that is a reflection of the quality of your content, the ban might not be much of a surprise. Users are not banned randomly. They are banned if they continue to post content that does not belong on the site.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't create different accounts to get around question bans. Secondly, some punctuation helps make questions readable, and thirdly - what exactly is is that you're asking here?

Comment: A link to the other account and/or other questions would greatly help to identify why they were closed (although I can harbor a guess).  So would punctuation and the occassional line break.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So why bother to create this kind of site if you are looking to ban people from asking questions?

Banning people from asking questions isn't the point of the site, but it's necessary to cut through the noise.  We want to help people with their programming problems, but there are so many people that need help that we have to prioritize.  People who demonstrate the ability to communicate good questions are given higher priority than people who repeatedly demonstrate that they either can't or don't care enough to try.

Answer (score 4):

> So why bother to create this kind of site if you are looking to ban
>   people from asking questions?

You only ask one question through all of your rambling post, so here's the answer to it: The goal of this site is not to help YOU find the solution to one specific situation. It is to catalog answers to questions that will help every person in the future who encounters the same situation. If your question is put forward in such a way that that goal cannot be met (for example, if your grammar is so bad that future readers won't be able to tell what your question is) then it is not suitable for this site.

Comment: And I am sure my grammar is not that bad! But I will try to make my question better next time! I believe that there are grammar Nazi out there that even minor grammatical mistakes will be caught! Thank you for your answer I now understand better about the site!